# how to access the last object ina an array of objects in react js

Tags: reactjs, mern

So, i have a list of objcets in an array stored in the databse. I am trying to display the object at the last index position using map function. It keeps displaying all the objects in the array,but i only want to show the last object. I will appreciate any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ConfirmBooking extends Component {
  state = {
    bookings: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api',)
      .then(res => {
        (console.log(res.data))
        this.setState({ bookings: res.data })

      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}
render() {

    return (
      <div>
        
    
    {/*{this.state.bookings.map((booking, i)=> {
      return (
        <div key={}>
         <h6>{`Name: ${booking.name}Service: ${booking.service} Date: ${booking.date} Cost: ${booking.cost}`}</h6> 
        
           </div>
      )
     })}
 */}
```

that is what i i have tried so far
[image: result i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `this.state.bookings.at(-1).name`. Index `-1` returns the last element of the array.

Comment: thanks a lot..but this method returns the last letter of every name in the object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.bookings?.length) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    const lastBooking = this.state.bookings.pop();
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>{`Name: ${lastBooking.name}Service: ${lastBooking.service} Date: ${lastBooking.date} Cost: ${lastBooking.cost}`}</h6>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks..but it still doesnt work,it shows nothing, the console shows this :
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior. I also folowed a tutorial to create an error boundary hoping it would solve the problem,but it did not

Comment: Okay so I've edited my answer. It should work now as I've tested it locally as well. The thing is that on the first render the bookings are not loaded as it is an async call.